# PreparedStatement SQLException

Tags: java, eclipse

I've serched for this before asking, but I don know if I'm doing something wrong or what.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
String query = "select nombre from DatosPersonas where nombre = '?'";

System.out.println("Introduce nomber a buscar");
String nom = teclado.next();
PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement)cn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, nom);
ResultSet rs1 = pstmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rs1.next()) {
    String nombre = rs1.getString("nombre");            
    System.out.println(nombre);
}
```

But got a

> SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

By the way, I'm new here and i've been programming for not so long and it's the first time I try to work with `PreparedStatement`. Thank you

Comment: That exception tell you that there is no parameter to set ("_number of parameters, which is 0_"). The reason, as answered, is that you don't have to worried about the quotes, `PreparedStatement.setString` will take care of the syntax. (That's the point of JDBC, to provide a standard solution working on different DB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have corrected the query with [f1sh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50599541/4391450), you will encounter a second problem.

You execute the wrong method. For the moment, you are not using the `PreparedStatement` instance you have define but execute the `String` query like a `Statement`.

You need to execute [`PrepatedStatement.executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29), not [`Statement.executeQuery(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

SO use `ResultSet rs1 = pstmt.executeQuery();`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `?` instead of `'?'`:

```
String query = "select nombre from DatosPersonas where nombre = ?";
```

This way the `?` gets treated as a placeholder that can be filled with `pstmt.setString(1, nom);`, otherwise it's a static string in your query.

Additionally, you use the wrong method, [as AxelH points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50599541/214525).

Comment: I've tried that too, but i get that Exception anways

Comment: @JoseLizarraga can you try that again? Because that sounds like you have a different problem.

Comment: ok, when I change '?' into ? I get this exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Comment: @JoseLizarraga if the ``?`` arrives at your SQL server (which the error message tells you), it's not being replaced by a real value. Your code doesn't reflect that and we cannot help you without the actual code.

Comment: The thing is.. when I don't use PreparedStatement and the query is like "select nombre from DatosPersonas where nombre = ' " +nom+ " ' "; It actually works

Comment: @JoseLizarraga then you're not using it correctly. I guess the code in the question is not the real code you're running?

Comment: thank you all guys, it was what the comment below says. It has to be ResultSet rs1 = pstmt.executeQuery();  (whitout query in brackets)

Comment: We^ve just created an infinite loop with our redirection @f1sh ;)

Comment: @AxelH any reader will be stuck forever. Our work here is done! :D

Answer (score -2):

try using this code

```
String query = "select nombre from DatosPersonas where nombre = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
if(!isInteger()){
    pstmt.setString(1, nom);
    ResultSet testExecutions = pstmt.executeQuery();
    while (pstmt.next()) {
        String nombre = pstmt.getString(1);            
    }
}
```

method for check string or not

```
public static boolean isInteger(String input )
{
    try
    {
         Integer.parseInt( input );
         return true;
    }
    catch( Exception )
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what makes you think that ``nombre`` might be an integer? And what happens if it is one? Then you don't replace the ``?`` in the query at all.

Comment: You have made some assumption that seems to be wrong. And you should explain the modification you have made. I see you have spotted the same problem (the method used) but it is not really visible... that's mostly why you end up with a negative score to my opinion.